# Installing Pencil on openSUSE

Tags: package-management, opensuse

I have installed openSUSE 11.4 today and I am trying to install [Pencil](http://www.pencil-animation.org/index.php?id=Download) on it. I downloaded the ArchLinux tarball from the site, and after extracting it, the *pencil.sh* file didn't install, giving a bash error (permission denied). I also tried searching for it on YaST, but didn't find it there.

Comment: How exactly did you run `pencil.sh`? Depending on what directory it tries to install to, you may need to run it as root.

Comment: @Gilles I am sure i'm trying everything as a superuser.

Comment: Try running the installer with `-x` (i.e., change the `#!` line to append `-x`, or run `sudo <shell> -x pencil.sh`. It should tell you everything it's doing, so you can see what it's trying to do when the error comes up. Then you can correct the error and try again, rinse, repeat.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use a OpenSUSE rpm? The OpenSUSE build service has rpms [here](https://build.opensuse.org/package/show?package=pencil&project=home%3adavjam79). If the packages aren't up to date, it will probably not be difficult to modify the packaging and rebuild a binary rpm.

Comment: Thanks for the input but this repository is meant to install [this](http://pencil.evolus.vn/en-US/Home.aspx) pencil. What I wish to install is [this](http://www.pencil-animation.org/) pencil. I wonder why it isn't available for rpm packages, its available for debian, windows and mac. But is there a way to install and use it on suse? ...except for taking the virtualbox's path.

Comment: @offengehirn: Sorry about the error. I've linked to the correct softeware this time, I think.